# Iterate node in Singly LinkedList for string input

Tags: java, string, insert, linked-list, nodes

I have a string called **input** which looks like:  `i52 i22 i36 i48 i32 d52 d32`

The `i` in front of each number, represents an **insert**, and the `d` a **delete**.

Each individual number needs to be inserted into a LinkedList as a node if it is an **insert** a the end of the LinkedList. Or deleted from the LinkedList if it is a **delete**. For a **delete**, it should remove the node for the number equal to `d##`.

My current code:

```
LinkedList<ListNode> list = new LinkedList<ListNode>();
ListNode header = new ListNode(null);

    for (String s: input.split(" ")){

        if (s.charAt(0) == 'i') {
            ListNode node = new ListNode(s);
            node.next = new ListNode(s);
            list.add(node);
        }
        else if (s.charAt(0) == 'd'){
            list.remove(s);
        }
    }
```

I know my code is messed up in the insert and the delete loop. How do you create a new Node, and connect it to the next Node?

---

The node class is:

```
class ListNode
{
    Object   element;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(Object theElement ) {
        this(theElement, null );
    }

    ListNode(Object theElement, ListNode n ) {
        element = theElement;
        next    = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: `s.substring(0)` is same as `s`. I think you should be using `s.charAt(0)` instead.

Comment: Why are you assigning the `next` of `node` to a new instance of `ListNode`?

Comment: Use [`.startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith\(java.lang.String\)) instead of what you're doing. What you're currently doing returns the entire string.

Comment: Edited my code to use s.charAt(0), could you help a bit with the node insertion?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java's LinkedList, all you have to do is:

```
if (s.charAt(0) == 'i') {
    ListNode node = new ListNode(s);
    list.add(node);
}
```

The LinkedList will take care of connecting nodes and 'linking' everything .

If you are making your own LinkedList, you have to define the add method in there. For example:

```
class LinkedList{
    ListNode head, tail;

    public void add(Object o){
        //Your add implementation
    }

    // ... other methods    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems to be redundant. Collection framework's `LinkedList<T>` will provide to link all the the elements `ListNode` you put in there. There is no need to use nodes with `next` field, unless you are trying to do something more.

Then your code doesn't insert the number `xy` for a `ixy` but the whole string. This can help:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

 for (String s: input.split(" ")){
     if(s.startsWith("i")){
         list.add(s.substring(1));
     }
     else if (s.charAt(0) == 'd'){
         list.remove(s.substring(1));
     }
 }
```